Object cannot be nil (key: NSFont) at NSMutableAttributedString in UILabel on iOS 17-18
I am encountering a runtime error in my iOS application when trying to set an NSAttributedString to a UILabel. The crash message on Firebase Crashlytics is:
*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: NSFont)
My Code Snippet
public final class HotelListPresentation {

    public init() {
        prepareRating()
    }
    

    private func prepareRating() {
        // Rating Status
        if let commentCount = hotel.commentCount, let ratingtext = hotel.averageScoreText {
            let commentText = (commentCount >= 3 ? " (\(commentCount) \(TextKey.hotelComment.localized))" : "")
            let boldFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .bold)
            let regularFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
            let titleColor = UIColor.blue
            let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString()
            mutableAttributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: ratingtext, attributes: [.font: boldFont, .foregroundColor: titleColor]))
            mutableAttributedString.append(NSAttributedString(string: commentText, attributes: [.font: regularFont, .foregroundColor: titleColor]))
            self.ratingStatusAttributed = mutableAttributedString
        }
    }
}


public final class HotelListTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet private var starsComponent: HotelStarsComponent!
    @IBOutlet private var ratingStackView: UIStackView!
    @IBOutlet private var ratingLabel: Label!
    @IBOutlet private var ratingBackgroundView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet private var ratingStatusLabel: Label!

    func configure(with data: HotelListPresentation) {
        let rating = data.averageScore ?? 0
        ratingLabel.text = rating.ratingDescription
        ratingBackgroundView.tintColor = data.averageScoreColor
        ratingStackView.isHidden = rating == 0 ? true : false
        ratingStatusLabel.attributedText = data.ratingStatusAttributed // Crash line
    }
}

This is the exact code flow, with unrelated sections removed for clarity. While I'm unable to share the entire codebase due to restrictions, this portion accurately represents the real flow concerning ratingStatusLabel.
Here is crashlytic's log,
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
*** -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: NSFont)
0
CoreFoundation
__exceptionPreprocess
1
libobjc.A.dylib
objc_exception_throw
2
CoreFoundation
-[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]
3
CoreFoundation
-[NSMutableDictionary addEntriesFromDictionary:]
4
Foundation
-[NSMutableAttributedString addAttributes:range:]
5
Foundation
-[NSAttributedString enumerateAttributesInRange:options:usingBlock:]
6
UIKitCore
-[NSAttributedString _ui_synthesizeAttributedSubstringFromRange:usingDefaultAttributes:]
7
UIKitCore
-[UILabel _synthesizedAttributedTextForContent:]
8
UIKitCore
-[UILabel _synthesizedAttributedText]
9
UIKitCore
-[UILabel _textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:includingShadow:]
10
UIKitCore
-[UILabel _intrinsicSizeWithinSize:]
11
UIKitCore
-[UILabel _ensureBaselineMetricsReturningBounds]
12
UIKitCore
-[UILabel _baselineOffsetFromBottom]
13
UIKitCore
-[UILabel _invalidateBaselineConstraints]
14
UIKitCore
-[UILabel _setContent:adjustingFontForAccessibilityTraits:adjustingFontForTypesettingLanguage:adjustingFontForTypesettingLanguageAwareLineHeightRatio:checkingForDifferences:]
15
UIKitCore
-[UILabel _setContent:]
16
UIKitCore
-[UILabel setAttributedText:]
17
obilet
HotelListTableViewCell.swift - Line 130
specialized HotelListTableViewCell.configure(with:imageSliderDataSource:) + 130
18
HotelApp
closure #1 in HotelListView.tableDataSource.getter

Has anyone encountered this issue? The crash is documented in Firebase Crashlytics, The funny part, it doesn’t happen consistently and only appear above iOS17, especially 17.6.1 and 18. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Which line crashes? Show us the crash log in more detail too, please.

Sorry Sir, now I added crashlytics logs. And it crashes when I assign this line
ratingStatusLabel.attributedText = mutableAttributedString

Try calling prepareRate if ratingStatusAttributed is nil before assigning it.

Yes as you said, it is called before I use ratingStatusAttributed. This crash happens only around iOS 17 18
